# Script to rebuild git history, applying code cleanup to every version

Tags: git, version-control, history, code-formatting

Has anyone got a script for git that can go through the history, check out each version, apply a cleanup script, then check the cleaned version into another repository?

I have some code which I've been developing, but I haven't been consistent with code formatting e.g. tabs vs spaces etc. I'd like to rewrite my entire history to be consistent with the new standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `git filter-branch` command does what you need.

For example:

```
# Make a backup!
cp -r <repo> <repo>.backup
cd <repo>
# Replace tabs with two spaces in all .cpp and .h files in all branches.
git filter-branch --tree-filter \
  "find \( -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.h' \) \
   -exec sed -i -re 's/\t/  /g' {} \;" -- --all
# Delete branch backups created by 'git filter-branch'.
# From the end of `man git filter-branch`; more cleanup
# suggestions there.
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | \
  xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
# You still have ../<repo>.backup, in case something went wrong.
```

But be careful... this transforms the git repository.
If somebody has a clone... it will not be connected to your new repo anymore.
From `man git filter-branch`:

> WARNING! The rewritten history will have different object names for
>   all the objects and will not converge with the original branch. You
>   will not be able to easily push and distribute the rewritten branch
>   on top of the original branch. Please do not use this command if
>   you do not know the full implications, and avoid using it anyway,
>   if a simple single commit would suffice to fix your problem. (See
>   the "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" section in git-rebase(1) for
>   further information about rewriting published history.)

Comment: I used the above to fixup about 15 commits across three branches in a personal repo when I realized the files I started with were full of tabs (I'd been using spaces in all my edits).